# How to combine a Mono and a Flux to create one object?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

I want to create one object and the object is made up of a Mono and a Flux.
Suppose there are 2 services `getPersonalInfo` and `getFriendsInfo`. `Person` needs both services to create an object. Zipping only takes the first element of `friends` object since there is only one `personalInfo` as it is Mono, but `friendsInfo` might have multiple `friend` objects in them. I want to set the `friendsInfo` to `friend` in `Person`.

```
class Person{
    String name;
    String age;
    List<Friend> friend;
}

Mono<PersonalInfo> personalInfo = personService.getPerson();// has name and age
Flux<Friend> friendsInfo = friendsService.getFriends();
// here I want to create Person object with personalInfo and friendsInfo
Flux<Person> person = Flux.zip(personalInfo, friendsInfo, (person, friend) -> new Person(person, friend));
```

Comment: So, you want to collect the friends from a Flux into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I assume you want to create a *single* person object which contains the name & age populated from your `Mono<PersonalInfo>`, and the friends list from your `Flux<Person>`.

Your attempt is pretty close:

```
Flux<Person> person = Flux.zip(Person, Friend, (person, friend) -> new Person(person, friend));
```

In particular, the `zip` operator with the overload that takes two publishers & a combinator is exactly the correct thing to use here. However, a couple of things that need changing:

- You want a *single* `Person` object, so that should be a `Mono<Person>` (and associated `Mono.zip()`.
- As per the comment, you need to convert your Flux into a list, which you can do so with the `collectList()` oeprator.

So putting that together, you end up with something like:

```
Mono<Person> person = Flux.zip(personalInfo, friendsInfo.collectList(), (personalInfo, friendsList) -> new Person(personalInfo, friendsList));
```

...which should give you what you're after.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! it works and I was looking for friendsInfo.collectList(). Again, really appreciate your help !

Comment: @michael-berry What in case I have more sources? For example, when I need to fetch data from N repositories and then create a new object from all of the data. Isn't there anything better than 'zip'? It looks a little bit awkward for me when for example +4 arguments are used in zip.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do same with **Mono.zip**

```
Mono<Person> person = Mono.zip(personalInfo, friendsInfo.collectList())
.map(zippedMono -> new Person(zippedMono.getT1(), zipeedMono.getT2());
```

I prefer to use Mono for code readability.